# Loop through files in a directory or a list

Tags: less

I am trying to generate multiple CSS classes for a single .css file to be used by the `body` element of a page to change the page's entire color scheme.

I have a folder of .less files containing variables `@base00` to `@base0F` for their specific color scheme (https://github.com/AndrewBelt/hack.chat/tree/master/client/base16) and would like to import each of these files for each CSS class name.

Here's some psuedocode to achieve what I need.

```
// This syntax does not exist in LESS
for each @scheme in ./base16/ {
    @import "@scheme"

    body.@{scheme} {
        background: @base00;
        color: @base07;
    }

    ...
}
```

I might have to think outside of the box for this one, like creating a Makefile to build by replacing variable by command line and concatenate each .css file generated by LESS to a single master .css file. But perhaps there is a more elegant way using pure LESS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no built-in file system functions/features Less. (It's designed to work in several environments and some of those do not even permit "directory sniffing"). If necessary one can write a plugin to provide such functionality, but I suppose in this case it would be more easy to do this externally.

Compiling and concatenating multiple files is not necessary the simplest method. For example you can simply generate Less file that imports all schemes and applies each to a main template, e.g. just a list of:

```
.scheme-name {
    @import "scheme-name";
    @import (multiple) "scheme-styles-template";
}
```

statements. Where `scheme-styles-template` is the same as your [`scheme.less`](https://github.com/AndrewBelt/hack.chat/blob/master/client/scheme.less) except `body` to be defined as:

```
body& {
    background: @base00;
    color: @base05;
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is a great method. I'll use this instead. I didn't realize variables were transfered over to included files after being defined in the root level file.